# OPENJSON with dynamic JSON key value pair

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, open-json

we are having a JSON document, where week numbers are dynamic keys. We want to load them to a relational table.

We are able to achieve relational resultset, if we hardcode the weeknumbers, as given below. But, it looks like a circuitous approach with hardcoded values. We want to make it dynamic.

Is there a way in TSQL to dynamically map the key value pairs as a relational table ?

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Measure": "Current Sales",
    "2019Week12": "33",
    "2019Week13": "33",
    "2019Week14": "34"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Measure": "Current Sales",
    "2019Week12": "",
    "2019Week13": "10",
    "2019Week14": "60"
  }]';

SELECT ID,Measure, WeekNumber, Sales
FROM
(   SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    with 
    ( ID int '$.ID',
    Measure VARCHAR(30) '$.Measure',
    [2019Week12] INT '$."2019Week12"',
    [2019Week13] INT '$."2019Week13"',
    [2019Week14] INT '$."2019Week14"'
    )
) as p
UNPIVOT
(
Sales FOR WeekNumber IN ([2019Week12],[2019Week13],[2019Week14]) 
) as unpvt
```

The result set we got is:

```
+----+---------------+------------+-------+
| ID |    Measure    | WeekNumber | Sales |
+----+---------------+------------+-------+
|  1 | Current Sales | 2019Week12 |    33 |
|  1 | Current Sales | 2019Week13 |    33 |
|  1 | Current Sales | 2019Week14 |    34 |
|  2 | Current Sales | 2019Week12 |     0 |
|  2 | Current Sales | 2019Week13 |    10 |
|  2 | Current Sales | 2019Week14 |    60 |
+----+---------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to use **content** in descriptive places. The **structure** of a generic document should not change with the content. It was much better to add an array of measure objects, each carrying the date and value in such called items.

Comment: Btw: Thank you very much for the good question including a [mcve] and your own attempt. This helps a lot when answering, +1 from my side.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo. The expected output is same as what I have put. Only thing is, it should be dynamic, instead of being hardcoded. one more thing, the JSON format is coming from another team and difficult to change. Unless very much needed, we should go with existing JSON format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not state the expected output. What I've got is: You want to get the same as above without the need to specify the names literally. I hope I got this correctly:

```sql
SELECT   JSON_VALUE(A.[value],'$.ID') AS ID
        ,JSON_VALUE(A.[value],'$.Measure') AS Measure
        ,B.[key] AS [varName]
        ,B.[value] AS [varValue]  
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JSON_VALUE(A.[value],'$.ID') ORDER BY B.[key]) RowIndex
FROM OPENJSON(@json) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.[value]) B
WHERE b.[key] NOT IN('ID','Measure');
```

The result

```
+----+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
| ID | Measure       | varName    | varValue | RowIndex |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 1  | Current Sales | 2019Week12 | 33       | 1        |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 1  | Current Sales | 2019Week13 | 33       | 2        |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 1  | Current Sales | 2019Week14 | 34       | 3        |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 2  | Current Sales | 2019Week12 |          | 1        |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 2  | Current Sales | 2019Week13 | 10       | 2        |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 2  | Current Sales | 2019Week14 | 60       | 3        |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

The idea in short:

- We use `OPENJSON()` to dive into your json string. This will return the two objects contained in a derived set `A`.
- Now we use `OPENJSON()` again passing in `A.[value]`, which is the json object itself.
- This would return all contained items, but we surpress `ID` and `Measurement` within `WHERE`.
- The two sepcial columns, `ID` and `Measurement` we fetch directly from `A.[value]` using `JSON_VALUE()`.

### UPDATE

One enhancement might be this:

```sql
SELECT   C.ID
        ,C.varName AS [varName]
        ,TRY_CAST(LEFT(C.varName,4) AS INT) AS MeasureYear
        ,TRY_CAST(RIGHT(C.varName,2) AS INT) AS MeasureWeek
        ,C.varContent AS [varValue]  
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C.ID ORDER BY C.varName) RowIndex
FROM OPENJSON(@json) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.[value]) B
CROSS APPLY (SELECT JSON_VALUE(A.[value],'$.ID') AS ID
                   ,JSON_VALUE(A.[value],'$.Measure') AS Measure
                   ,B.[key] AS varName
                   ,B.[value] AS varContent) C
WHERE C.varName NOT IN('ID','Measure');
```

The idea: Adding one more `APPLY` allows to return the values as *regular columns*. This makes it easier to proceed with the values and makes this lot more readable.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. Very helpful. I wish I could upvote one more time.